# Share data between local service and the hosting activity

Tags: android

I need to share data between a local service and its hosting activity,
I am using `sendBroadcast` in order to send data to the hosting activity from the service, but what if I wanted to send data back to the service from the hosting activity?

So I though of creating a static method on the service, and call it from the activity, and through it send the parameter, but then I can't do operations like show a toast inside that static method (which is inside the service)...

This is because you can't use `myclass.this` inside a static method, I guess there are more limitations...

Maybe there is another solution? Maybe there is a proper way for this task?

Thanks,

moshik.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sharedpreferences file and store the data in there. That way both activity and service will be able to access and update the same data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on your use cases, however another option (aside from using intents / shared preferences) is to extend the Application class and put your object onto that.

The benefit of this is that you don't need to worry about intents, but it may not be the best option for your scenarios.

I wrote a [tutorial here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/), give that a try

**disclaimer : this is just one way to solve an issue, not THE way..*